# Error in plotting for multiple groups using ggplot and dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(year = rep(2012:2015, each = 9), month = rep(4:12, times = 4), 
            y = runif(36), x = runif(36))
```

I am trying to plot y and x for each month across all years separately.

```
for(m in unique(dat$month)){
       test <- dat[dat$month == m,]
       ggplot(test, aes(x = x, y= y)) + geom_point()
     }
```

I tried to do a dplyr solution to this:

```
ggplot(dat %>% group_by(month) %>%  
                 aes(x = x, y = y, colour = factor(year))) +
    geom_point()
```

`Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`

Why is this error? and how do I show all the plots in a single page?

**EDIT**
I think if downvoting, the concerned person should specify why it is being downvoted and what aspect of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is not being met.

Comment: `ggplot(dat %>% group_by(month),  
         aes(x = x, y = y, colour = factor(year))) +
  geom_point()` ?

Comment: Thanks. How do I show all the plots in a single page?

Comment: Not sure if you wanted what jafSF showed, and then a plot per month, but I think that would be `ggplot(dat %>% group_by(month), aes(x = x, y = y, colour = factor(year))) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ factor(month))`

Comment: btw, I'm not sure I grasp why you're using dplyr in your call. Can't you plot the same plot as jaySF posted with this call `ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = factor(year))) + geom_point()`? And then the code in my previous comment as `ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = factor(year))) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ factor(month))`?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not sure. Normally I'd expect it to be marked as duplicate (which it might be) or at least mentioned what else is wrong with it.

Comment: Downvoting is a power misused without a clear explanation of why it is being downvoted. I hope stackoverflow fixes it

Comment: The error is because you are piping your data to an `aes()` object. `dat %>% group_by(month) %>%  aes(...`

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what "for each month across all years separately" means. But here's my interpretation

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(year = rep(2012:2015, each = 9), month = rep(4:12, times = 4), 
                  y = runif(36), x = runif(36))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, color = factor(year))) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(year~month)
```

[image]

Comment: I was looking for this `ggplot(dat , aes(x = x, y = y, colour = factor(year))) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ factor(month))` but your solution also covers the other aspects I want to do. So I am accepting this answer. Thank you.